# How to check if big query table exists with spark/scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-bigquery

I need to do certain operation on a set of BQ tables but I want to do the operation if and only if I know for certain that all the BQ tables exist.

I have checked the google big query package and it has a sample to read the data from BQ tables - fine But what if my tables are really huge? I can't load all the tables for existence check as it would take too much time and seems redundant.

Is there another way to achieve this? I would be very glad if I could get some pointers in the right direction.

Thank you in advance.

Gaurav

Answer (score 2):

`spark.read.option(...).load` does will not load all the objects into a dataframe. 
`spark.read.option(...)` returns a `DataFrameReader`. when you call `load` on it , it will test the connection and issue a query like

`SELECT * FROM (select * from objects) SPARK_GEN_SUBQ_11 WHERE 1=0`

The query will not scan any records and will error out when the table does not exist. I am not sure about the BigQuery driver but jdbc drivers throw a java exception here, which you need to handle in a `try {} catch {}` block.

Thus you can just call load, catch exceptions and check wether all dataframes could be instantiated. Here is some example code

```
def query(q: String) = {
   val reader = spark.read.format("bigquery").option("query", q)
  try {
    Some(reader.load())
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => None
  }
}

val dfOpts =  Seq(
  query("select * from foo"),
  query("select * from bar"),
  query("select * from baz")
)


if(dfOpts.exists(_.isEmpty)){
  println("Some table is missing");
}
```

Comment: I see there is no official spark sql connector from google. There is one , but it is in beta https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector

However even with official driver. Wont it error out on `sc.newAPIHadoopRDD` if the table does not exist? if so, you can use a similar approach here, by catching those exception and continue only if none was raised

Answer (score 1):

You could use the method tables.get

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/get

Otherwise, you can run BG CLI command in a bash script, which can be called from your spark program.

Comment: Thank you. Let me check this option. Seems promising. :). I will get back shortly.